# Como fazer paginação PHP e MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, paginação

Eu quero é fazer uma paginação no meu blog. Não vou ter na primeira página 50 posts, então quero limitar a página para os últimos 15 posts adicionados e depois ao clicar no botão "older posts" irá me mostrar os posts mais antigos. No fundo não quero carregar a página cheia de posts, basicamente é como o histórico do Google, temos o nosso histórico e não aparece tudo na página desde que o instalamos, temos botões a dizer "mais antigo", "mais recente".

Comment: Bem-vindo ao Stack Overflow em Português! Os post's vêm da BD? Antes de mostrar já sabes quantos post's são?

Comment: sim os post's vêm da bd

Comment: Mostra o código que tens para ser mais fácil responder a pergunta.

Comment: o codigo para o mostrar os posts ainda nao estao feitos eu queria uma base

Comment: Olá, bem-vindo ao [pt.so]. O que você está perguntando envolve vários problemas, você poderia [edit] a pergunta indicando em que parte está com dificuldade? Seria sobre como pegar do banco os posts por blocos? Ou sobre como exibir isso na página?

Comment: @cloud Acho que ninguém entendeu bem sua pergunta como já comentado acima. Você está fazendo um blog do zero? Então provavelmente sua dúvida é na verdade sobre como consultar uma base de dados e deveria descrever quais as tecnologias estão sendo usadas. Ou seria um template Wordpress? Nesse caso há comandos específicos do wordpress para fazer a paginação para você. Enfim, você precisa detalhar mais o que quer, caso contrário não ninguém vai simplesmente criar um blog de exemplo só para responder a esta pergunta.

Comment: peço desculpa pela minha explicaçao, sim eu comecei um blog do zero mas ja tenho tudo as divs todas http://gyazo.com/817d5deec09f32476250502fe61cc6f2 ja estou a adicionar a partir do painel administrativo com ligação á base de dados, o que vai acontecer é que o usuário do site vai colocar post's e mais post's e pagina blog vai ficar muito grande, cheio de posts tipo isto http://gyazo.com/44a9a885fc5761e7a6173b1b943f2802

Comment: o que eu quero é limitar os post imaginemos quando a pagina blog tiver 100 posts so vai mostrar os 20 ultimos posts adicionados recentemente e depois terei o botao "older posts" que me irá depois mostrar o resto dos posts mais antigos

Comment: http://gyazo.com/5a7fa312a7114e8f2fd9f210d3c77429 é isto que quero um botao para mostrar os posts antigos ao clicar neles vai me actualizar e mostrar os posts mais antigos

Comment: Esse limitar também é conhecido como paginação, na hora de fazer a consulta é necesario usar um `limit/off set` e um `order by <campo> desc` por exemplo por id ou data de criação isso vai trazer os últimos registros inseridos

Comment: Como o perdeu já disse, seu problema é em fazer **paginação**. Reformule sua pergunta para que ela seja sobre esse assunto, por exemplo: "Como fazer paginação em PHP e MySQL?". Então provavelmente vai haver respostas para você.

Comment: cloud, coloca esses detalhes dos seus comentários na pergunta.

Comment: Creio que seja exatamente o que o @perdeu comentou, o que você busca é o comando **LIMIT** do MySQL.

Comment: Como o @bfavaretto disse, seria apenas um conjunto de resultados de uma única categoria ? Ou seriam vários resultados  de categorias diferentes ? Explica melhor, se possível.

Answer (score 12):

Segue exemplo de um código para paginação, todas as linhas estão comentadas.

```
<?php
    //inclusão da conexão com banco de dados
    require('config/conectaBd.php');
    //A quantidade de valor a ser exibida
    $quantidade = 3;
    //a pagina atual
    $pagina     = (isset($_GET['pagina'])) ? (int)$_GET['pagina'] : 1;
    //Calcula a pagina de qual valor será exibido
    $inicio     = ($quantidade * $pagina) - $quantidade;

    //Monta o SQL com LIMIT para exibição dos dados  
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM novidades ORDER BY  data DESC LIMIT $inicio, $quantidade";
    //Executa o SQL
    $qr  = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
    //Percorre os campos da tabela
    while($ln = mysql_fetch_assoc($qr)){?>

                <div id="noticias">
                <div style="border-bottom:1px dotted #CCC; width:700px; padding:15px; margin-left:-65px;">
            <!--echo '<div style="color:#999; font-size:10px; width:auto; margin-top:2px; margin-bottom:-3px;">'.formata_data($data).'</div>';-->

                <div id="titulo">
        <?php echo $ln['titulo'];?>
                </div>
        <img src="fotos/<?php echo $ln['foto'];?> " style="width:250px; float:left; margin-right:25px; margin-bottom:15px; padding:10px; border:2px solid #D8D8D8;"/>
        <div id="descricao">
        <?php echo $ln['descricao']?></div>
                </div>
                </div>
                </div>
        <?php }?>


        <?php
  /**
   * SEGUNDA PARTE DA PAGINAÇÃO
   */
  //SQL para saber o total
  $sqlTotal   = "SELECT id FROM novidades";
  //Executa o SQL
  $qrTotal    = mysql_query($sqlTotal) or die(mysql_error());
  //Total de Registro na tabela
  $numTotal   = mysql_num_rows($qrTotal);
  //O calculo do Total de página ser exibido
  $totalPagina= ceil($numTotal/$quantidade);
   /**
    * Defini o valor máximo a ser exibida na página tanto para direita quando para esquerda
    */
   $exibir = 3;
   /**
    * Aqui montará o link que voltará uma pagina
    * Caso o valor seja zero, por padrão ficará o valor 1
    */
   $anterior  = (($pagina - 1) == 0) ? 1 : $pagina - 1;
   /**
    * Aqui montará o link que ir para proxima pagina
    * Caso pagina +1 for maior ou igual ao total, ele terá o valor do total
    * caso contrario, ele pegar o valor da página + 1
    */
   $posterior = (($pagina+1) >= $totalPagina) ? $totalPagina : $pagina+1;
   /**
    * Agora monta o Link paar Primeira Página
    * Depois O link para voltar uma página
    */
  /**
    * Agora monta o Link para Próxima Página
    * Depois O link para Última Página
    */
    ?>
    <div id="navegacao">
        <?php
        echo '<a href="?pagina=1">primeira</a> | ';
        echo "<a href=\"?pagina=$anterior\">anterior</a> | ";
    ?>
        <?php
         /**
    * O loop para exibir os valores à esquerda
    */
   for($i = $pagina-$exibir; $i <= $pagina-1; $i++){
       if($i > 0)
        echo '<a href="?pagina='.$i.'"> '.$i.' </a>';
  }

  echo '<a href="?pagina='.$pagina.'"><strong>'.$pagina.'</strong></a>';

  for($i = $pagina+1; $i < $pagina+$exibir; $i++){
       if($i <= $totalPagina)
        echo '<a href="?pagina='.$i.'"> '.$i.' </a>';
  }

   /**
    * Depois o link da página atual
    */
   /**
    * O loop para exibir os valores à direita
    */

    ?>
    <?php echo " | <a href=\"?pagina=$posterior\">próxima</a> | ";
    echo "  <a href=\"?pagina=$totalPagina\">última</a>";
    ?>
```

Comment: Você pode até usar o exemplo do **Douglas Bernadino**, mas use PDO ou mysqli. Extensões mysql estão depreciadas e mysqli em um futuro breve também!

Answer (score 3):

Irei resumir uma técnica que uso usando o `OFFSET` do MySQL.

```
<?php

$limite = 15; // Limite por página

// Pega página atual, se houver e for válido (maior que zero!)
if( isset( $_GET['pagina'] ) && (int)$_GET['pagina'] >= 0){
    $pagina = (int)$_GET['pagina'];
}else{
    $pagina = 0;
}

// Calcula o offset
$offset = $limite * $pagina;

// Se for 0 será 15*0 que será 0, começando do inicio
// Se for 1 será 15*1 que irá começar do 15 ignorando os 15 anteriores. ;)

$postagem = $mysqli->query('SELECT * FROM `post` ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT '.$limite.' OFFSET '.$offset);
?>
```

Depois disto basta exibir como quiser, por exemplo:

```
<?php

while($info = $postagem->fetch_array()){
// Loop finito para repetir para cada linha existente
?>

<!-- HTML PARA EXIBIÇÃO -->
<h1><?= $info['titulo'] ?></h1> 
<div class="data"><?= $info['dataHumano'] ?></div>
<div class="descricao"><?= $info['desc'] ?></div>
<!-- HTML PARA EXIBIÇÃO -->

<?php
}
?>
```

Para paginar utilize algo similar ao:

> Isto irá acionar o `$_GET['pagina']` mencionado na primeira parte.

```
<?php
if($pagina !== 0){ // Sem isto irá exibir "Página Anterior" na primeira página.
?>
<a href="meulink.com?pagina=<?php echo $pagina-1; ?>">Página Anterior</a>
<?php
}
?>
<a href="meulink.com?pagina=<?php echo $pagina+1; ?>">Página Posterior</a>
```

Acredito que isto está simples e será suficiente, tentei comentar o máximo possível.

**Nota:**

> O *link de próxima página* será exibido mesmo se for a última página possível! Para resolver isso acho que a melhor solução é selecionar todos as linhas e dividir por 15 e verificar se o  usuário não está na última página.
>
> Não utilizei o `bind_param` por se tratar apenas de números inteiros e apenas no LIMIT e OFFSET, mas utilize o `bind_param` se houver outros parâmetros no `WHERE`, por exemplo categorias.

Answer (score 0):

Meu site tem 180 produtos , pode usar meu codigo funciona perfeitamente:

```
<?php
echo'<table width="88%" height="10" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"><tr>';
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=loja", "root", "");
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM `produtos` ORDER BY `id` ASC ");
$stmt->execute( );
$linha = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
while($linha = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo'<br>';
    echo'<p><td align=center ><h2><font size="5" face="Trebuchet MS">'.$linha['nome'].'</font></font></p></h2>';
    echo "<div align=center ><img src='".$linha['foto']."' width='160' height='160' border='0'></p>";
    echo '<a href="carrinho.php?acao=add&id='.$linha['id'].'"><button type="button" name="" value="" class="quero">Eu Quero!</button>';
}
echo "</tr></table>";
?>
```