# Paginação script PHP

Tags: php, mysql, paginação

Gostaria de saber como consigo realizar uma paginação em PHP(no caso, 10 itens por página).

A exibição está sendo feita desse modo:

```
<?php foreach($pdo->query('SELECT * FROM videos ORDER BY id DESC') as $c): ?>
    <li>
        <p>
            <strong>
                <?php echo $c['title'];?>
            </strong>
        </p>
        <a title="<?php echo $c['title'] ?>" class="lightbox" href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/<?php echo $c['video_ed'] ?>?rel=0&amp;wmode=transparent">
            <img src="http://i1.ytimg.com/vi/<?php echo $c['video_ed'] ?>/default.jpg" alt="<?php echo $c['title']; ?>" />
        </a>

    </li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Não consegui ainda encontrar um método que funcione...

Comment: Veja a resposta aqui : http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/26303/como-fazer-pagina%C3%A7%C3%A3o-php-e-mysql

Answer (score 8, accepted):

De forma bem simples:

```
$page = isset($_GET['page']) (int) $_GET['page'] : 1;

$limit = 10;

$offset = ($page * $limit) - $limit; 
// Gera 0,1,2,3, para cada página incrementada

$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM minha_tabela LIMIT $offset,$limit"); 

$stmt->execute(); 

$resultados = $stmt->fetchAll();

$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT count(*) as count 
FROM minha_Tabela'); 

$stmt->execute();

$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$total_de_paginas = $row['count'];
```

No HTML para gerar os links, você faz assim:

```
<?php for($i = 1; $i <= $total_de_paginas; $i++): ?>
    <a href="?<?php echo http_build_query(array('page' => $i)) ?>">
      <?php echo $i ?>
   </a>

<?php endfor ?>
```

Se você executar o foreach no seu `$resultados`, virá os resultados da consulta paginados.

Comment: Simples e objetivo +1, da para usar placeholders no limite/off set se quiser.

Comment: Muito bom! Agradeço a ajuda.