# PDO Paginação - Fatal error: Out of memory

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

Estou fazendo uma paginação, porém a mesma está gerando um erro de memória.

Existe alguma maneira de otimizar ou corrigir a falha? Ou é no servidor mesmo?

**Nota**: o `php.ini` esta setado a memoria em 512.

```
if (!(isset($_GET['pagenum']))) {
    $pagenum = 1;
} else {
    $pagenum = $_GET['pagenum'];
}
$page_limit = ($_GET["show"] <> "" && is_numeric($_GET["show"]) ) ? $_GET["show"] : 30;

try {
    $keyword = trim($_GET["keyword"]);
    if (!empty($keyword)) {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM noticias WHERE conteudo LIKE :keyword OR titulo LIKE :keyword ORDER BY Nid DESC";
        $stmt = $DB->prepare($sql);

        $likekeyword = "%".$keyword."%";
        $stmt->bindParam(':keyword', $likekeyword, PDO::PARAM_STR);

    } else {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM noticias WHERE 1 ORDER BY Nid DESC";
        $stmt = $DB->prepare($sql);
    }

    $stmt->execute();
    $total_count = count($stmt->fetchAll());

    $last = ceil($total_count / $page_limit);

    if ($pagenum < 1) {
        $pagenum = 1;
    } elseif ($pagenum > $last) {
        $pagenum = $last;
    }

    $lower_limit = ($pagenum - 1) * $page_limit;
    $lower_limit = ($lower_limit < 0) ? 0 : $lower_limit;

    $sql2 = $sql . " limit " . ($lower_limit) . " ,  " . ($page_limit) . " ";

    $stmt = $DB->prepare($sql2);

    if ($keyword <> "" ) {
        $stmt->bindParam(':keyword', $likekeyword, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    }

    $stmt->execute();
    $results = $stmt->fetchAll();
} catch (Exception $ex) {
    echo $ex->getMessage();
}
```

codigo exibe contadores

```
 <div class="col-lg-12 center">
  <ul class="pagination pagination-sm">
   <?php
   for ($i = 1; $i <= $last; $i++) {
   if ($i == $pagenum) {
    ?>
   <li class="active"><a href="javascript:void(0);" ><?php echo $i ?></a></li>
            <?php
          } else {
            ?>
            <li><a href="noticias_listar.php?pagenum=<?php echo $i; ?>&keyword=<?php echo $_GET["keyword"]; ?>" class="links"  onclick="displayRecords('<?php echo $page_limit; ?>', '<?php echo $i; ?>');" ><?php echo $i ?></a></li>
            <?php
          }
        }
        ?>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: Você precisa adicionar o `limit` naquele select com dois `likes`.

Comment: mais o limit e difinifo pela variavel $page_limit , ou é a forma que fiz que ta errado?

Comment: Na sua consulta, depois de `ORDER BY Nid DESC` adicione `LIMIT 0, 70` apenas para teste veja se vai acontecer o erro. Do jeito que está a consulta é retornado o maior número de registros, com esse `limit` serão retornados apenas os 70 primeiros, claro vc precisa alterar esse mecanismo para funcionar de forma dinâmica. Veja [essa resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/94890/91)

Comment: colocando no select com 2 likes o erro continou o mesmo ja colocando no outro foi o seguinte ->  SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'limit 0 , 30' at line 1

Comment: Coloca ai a consulta que deu erro.

Comment: E outra você está executando a mesma consulta duas vezes ... uma sem limit e outra com.

Comment: rray $sql = "SELECT * FROM noticias WHERE 1 ORDER BY Nid DESC LIMIT 0,30";  no caso estou executando 2 pq se o usuario nao digitar nada ele lista tudo se digitar no campo de pesquisa ele busca com a outra

Comment: Dei um tapa na pergunta :)

Comment: Do jeito que o sistema está é mais provável receberes erros do que o resultado esperado, um exemplo óbvio é este - ` $total_count = count($stmt->fetchAll());` - que capaz de causar sobrecarga, e ainda mantém os valores, e depois ainda é executada outra consulta, com o método `fetchAll()`. Existem funções próprias para contar o número de linhas encontradas, e existem também cláusulas próprias para contar o número de linhas, exemplos são a função `COUNT` do SQL e o `fetchColumns` ou simplesmente `rowCount` para o `PDO`.

Comment: ` $total_count = count($stmt->fetchAll());` mais aqui nao esta usando exatamente o count? existe diferenca entre rowCount($stmt->fetchAll()) e  count($stmt->fetchAll())?

Comment: Existe, e muita, sendo que o `count` itera cada posição da array, propriedades de um objeto, e o método [rowCount](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php) é basicamente um aditivo à consulta, ou seja, ele já existe no momento em que é executada uma consulta, e além do mais, não se usa com o `fetchAll`, usa-se diretamente na consulta `$stmt->rowCount`, tal como a função [columnCount](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.columncount.php). Outra opção é a uma função nativa do próprio SQL - [COUNT](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_count.asp).

Answer (score 2):

É uma péssima ideia usar `PDOStatement::fetchAll()` se você não tem ideia da quantidade de registros que será retornada e armazenada na memória. Tenha em mente que a classe `PDOStatement` funciona também como um iterador, evitando o uso premeditado de memória. No seu caso, utilize `PDOStatement::rowCount()` para ter em mãos o número de registros e itere com o método `PDOStatement::fetch()`.

Eu particularmente prefiro executar uma query com `COUNT(*)` antes, para obter o número total de registros, e outra query definitiva para recuperá-los, usando mecanismos com `OFFSET` e `LIMIT`. Não faz sentido requisitar linhas ao banco de dados que não serão utilizadas durante a execução.

Answer (score 1):

Pelo erro, aquela com consulta com where parece ser o problema, o idela é paginar ela, outro problema é que essa consulta é executada duas vezes.
Veja:

```
} else {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM noticias WHERE 1 ORDER BY Nid DESC";
    $stmt = $DB->prepare($sql);
}
$stmt->execute(); //primeira vez que a consulta é executada.
$total_count = count($stmt->fetchAll());

//... código omitido.

$sql2 = $sql . " limit " . ($lower_limit) . " ,  " . ($page_limit) . " ";
$stmt = $DB->prepare($sql2);

//código omitido.

$stmt->execute(); //segunda vez que a mesma consulta é executada.
$results = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

Acredito que o código pode ser simplificado dessa forma:

```
$pagenum = isset($_GET['pagenum']) ? $_GET['pagenum'] : 1;

$limite = ($_GET["show"] <> "" && is_numeric($_GET["show"]) ) ? $_GET["show"] : 30;
$offset = ($pagenum * $limit) - $limit; 


try {
    $keyword = trim($_GET["keyword"]);
    if (!empty($keyword)) {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM noticias WHERE conteudo LIKE :keyword OR titulo LIKE :keyword ORDER BY Nid DESC";
        $stmt = $DB->prepare($sql);

        $likekeyword = "%".$keyword."%";
        $stmt->bindParam(':keyword', $likekeyword, PDO::PARAM_STR);

    } else {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM noticias WHERE 1 ORDER BY Nid DESC LIMIT :limit, :offset";
        $stmt = $DB->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bindValue(':limit', $limite, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindValue(':offset', $offset, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    }

    $stmt->execute();
    $results = $stmt->fetchAll();

    //Faz o calculo do número de registros por página
    $total_registros = $DB->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM noticias")->fetchColumn() or die($db->error);
    $paginas = floor($total_registros / $limite);



} catch (Exception $ex) {
    echo $ex->getMessage();
}


//imprime os resultados e os link das páginas(segundo for).
foreach($results as $item){
    printf("id: %d - título: %s - idade: %d <br>", $item['id'], $item['titulo']);
}


for($i = 1; $i <= $paginas; $i++){
    printf('<a href="?page=%d">%d</a>|', $i, $i);
}
```

**Referência:**

[Paginação script PHP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/94890/91)

Comment: Bom não tive oportunidade de testar, entrei em contato com o pessoal da hospedagem e eles disseram que desbloquearam algo no apache quanto ao erro. Mesmo assim testei as alterações que vc postou na resposta e ok, funcionou quase perfeito exceto pelo contadores de paginas que ficou apenas na primeira pagina ( atualizei a pergunta com o codigo da onde exibe os contadores de pagina)

Comment: O link da sua página precisa ter duas informações, o limite por exemplo 30 e o off set que é a 'posição atual' do registro para frente que deve ser exibido. @ArsomNolasco

Answer (score 1):

Experimenta separar algumas das variáveis das funções, assim consegues visualizar melhor o que se está a passar.

Como já antes disse nos comentários, existem várias alternativas à função `count` que estavas a usar juntamente com o método `fetchAll`, e que estavam a ser repetidas desnecessárias vezes.Lembrando também que o `fetchAll` possui como método predefinido de busca o `PDO::FETCH_BOTH`.

```
<?php

$dsn = "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=exemplo;charset=utf8;";
$pagina = isset($_GET['pagina']) ? (int)$_GET['pagina'] : 1;
$pagina = ($pagina > 0) ? $pagina : 1;
$termo_busca = isset($_GET['s']) ? (string)$_GET['s'] : '';
$por_pagina = 3;
$offset = ($pagina -1) * $por_pagina;
$dados = array();
$total = "";
$i = 1;

try {
    $pdo = new pdo($dsn, 'root', '');
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM noticias WHERE conteudo LIKE :busca OR titulo LIKE :busca ORDER BY Nid DESC LIMIT {$por_pagina} OFFSET {$offset}";
    if($prepare = $pdo->prepare($sql)){
        if($prepare->execute(array(':busca'=>'%'.$termo_busca.'%'))){
            while($linha = $prepare->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)){
                $dados[] = $linha;
            }
            # condição para corrigir a paginacao quando existe um termo de busca
            if($termo_busca):
                $where = "WHERE conteudo LIKE '%{$termo_busca}%' OR titulo LIKE '%{$termo_busca}%'";
            else:
                $where = "";
            endif;  

            $count = $pdo->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM notcias {$where}")->fetchColumn();
            $total = ceil($count/$por_pagina);
        }
    }
} catch(PDOException $e){
    die($e->getMessage());
}

# imprimir os resultados e paginar
if($dados){
    foreach($dados as $object){
        print $object->titulo . "<br/>";
    }

    do{
        if($termo_busca):
            print "<a href=\"{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?s={$termo_busca}&pagina={$i}\"> {$i} </a>";
        else:
            print "<a href=\"{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?pagina={$i}\"> {$i} </a>";
        endif;

        $i++;
    } while($i <= $total);
} else {
    print "Nenhum resltado encontrado <a href=\"{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}\">voltar</a>";
}

?>
```

Esta consulta é interna, e retorna o número de resultados correspondentes ao critério fornecido:

```
$pdo->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM notcias {$where}"); # retorna COUNT(*)=> #numero
```

A função `fetchColumn` retorna uma única coluna na seguinte linha do conjunto de resultados. Adicionando à consulta anteriror, ela retorna o resultado exato, sendo que a função `COUNT(*)` retorna apenas uma coluna para como resultado da consulta.

```
$pdo->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM notcias {$where}")->fetchColumn();
```

Ou podes ainda usar, a consulta desta forma:

```
$pdo->query("SELECT * FROM exemplo {$where}")->rowCount();
```

Existem ainda outras formas de contar o número de linhas existente no banco de dados sem sobrecarregar a memória, só tens de procurar.