# Erro com GET em paginação PHP

Tags: php

Estou tentando adaptar os links relativos para absolutos em meu script de paginação. Porém, sempre que tento avançar ou voltar uma pagina, o link fica da seguinte forma:
`http://localhost/textos?pag=2?pag=3`

**Script:**

```
<?php
$url          = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
$urlEndereco  = $_SERVER ['REQUEST_URI'];
?>
<table border="1">
   <tr>
<?php
if($pag!=1){
   echo "<td><a href='http://".$url.$urlEndereco."?pag=".($pag-1)."'> Página Anterior</a></td>"; 
}
if($contador<=$maximo){
   echo "<td>Existe apenas uma única página</td>";
}
else{
   for($i=1;$i<=$paginas;$i++){
if($pag==$i){
   echo "<td  style='background: red'><a href='http://".$url.$urlEndereco."?pag=".$i."'> ".$i."</a></td>";
}else{
   echo "<td><a href='http://".$url.$urlEndereco."?pag=".$i."'> ".$i."</a></td>";
}
}
}
if($pag!=$paginas){
   echo "<td><a href='http://".$url.$urlEndereco."?pag=".($pag+1)."'> Próxima Página</a></td>";
}
?>
</tr>
</table>
```

Porém, se eu utilizar o código abaixo, funciona normalmente. Mas acontece que irei utilizar a paginação com um include em varias página para deixar o código limpo, tendo um controle mais fácil.

```
echo "<td><a href='textos?pag=".($pag+1)."'> Próxima Página</a></td>";
```

Também percebi que a $urlEndereco que está causando isso, uma vez que ela faz o `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];`, retornando sempre o final da url: `http://localhost/textos?pag=2?pag=3`

Comment: Relacionada: [Paginação script PHP](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/94890/91)

Comment: Não necessariamente, o problema dele é como URL, o que não tem haver diretamente com o assunto tratado nesse outro post de paginação.

Comment: Sim, mas de qualquer forma foi de grande ajuda. Obrigado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existem vários métodos para resolver.

**Causa:**

> O `$urlEndereco` está inserindo o `?pag=2`, quando tenta adicionar o
>   novo `?pag=` ele está duplicando.

**Resolver:**

> Remova o `2` da `?pag=2` e apenas inseria o novo número em seu lugar.

Utilize o seguinte para remover o último número:

```
    <?php
    if(isset($_GET['pag'])){ 
   // Se existir pag ele corta!

      $tamanhoGET = 0 - strlen($_GET['pag']); 
    // Terá o tamanho do GET, ou seja, 1 caractere ou 2...
    // O número zero é para torna-lo negativo!

      $urlEndereco = substr($_SERVER ['REQUEST_URI'], 0, $tamanhoGET);
    // Logo o http://localhost/textos?pag=2 irá se tornar http://localhost/textos?pag=
    // Se tiver na página 12 irá cortar os 2 ultimos números.

    }else{
      $urlEndereco = $_SERVER ['REQUEST_URI'].'?pag=';
   // Este é o caminho padrão

    }  


    ?>
```

Agora apenas altere o seu `echo` para apenas inserir o número, ao invés de todo o parâmetro.

Utilize algo similar:

```
<?php
     echo "<td><a href='http://".$url.$urlEndereco.($pag+1)."'> Próxima Página</a></td>";
    // O $urlEndereço não terá o número, agora irá possuir o $pag+1. 
?>
```

**Ideia Geral:**

Acredito que está auto-explicativo, mas em geral ele irá remover o número do parâmetro e inserir um novo número, ao invés de acrescentar um novo parâmetro como estava fazendo, o que acabava por duplica-lo.

Comment: Olá amigo! Após utilizar seu método, retornou dois erros: o link agora ficou http://localhost2/ quando eu passo para proxima pagina. E quando eu acesso localhost/textos, é exibida a seguinte mensagem: Undefined index: pag in C:\wamp\www\scripts\paginacao.php on line 3, e a linha 3 é a variavel $tamanhoGET

Comment: Fiz as alterações necessárias

Comment: Obrigado e parabéns. Fiz as alterações e funcionou perfeitamente. Quero tirar outra dúvida simples, mesmo não tendo muito a ver com a pergunta: O google carrega as paginações? por exemplo, nos resultados irá aparecer textos?pag=1 ? se sim, como eu removo? para que apareça apenas www.site.com.br/textos. Quanto a url amigavel, irei fazer as alterações para que fique textos/pagina/1 ou pagina-1, se souber me ajudar também.

Comment: Isso deve ser modificado no htaccess para url amigável. No caso do Google ele não usa página, mas sim o valor do OFFSET. Existe o `start=` no URL. Sendo assim, a segunda página é `start=10`, na terceira é `start=20`. Ou seja, se colocar `google.com/search?q=busca&start=50` vai cair na página 6.

Comment: Posso não ter entendido muito bem. Se se refere ao SEO, ele irá rastrear, mas pode também fazer um `sitemap` dinâmico, apontando cada página. Mas cuidado para não ter duplicações, principalmente se for ?pag=0, por exemplo ser repetido de sem `?pag=0`, por exemplo, o ideal é que use o header location nestes casos.

Answer (score 1):

Tente dessa forma pois o PHP_SELF é relativo a raiz do documento. Elimine o *$urlEndereco*

```
$url = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
```

Comment: O método que me passou é válido. Porém, ele busca o endereço relativo, e isso faz com que pegue as sub-pastas do meu site e também a extensão .php, causando problemas com minhas url's amigáveis.

Comment: Então tente com HTTP_REFERER.

Comment: Não sei  porque, mas causou lentidão em cada requisição com F5 na página..

Comment: Você ainda pode usar SCRIPT_NAME  que retorna somente o nome do arquivo, não tendo a necessidade de carregar o HOST.