# Curiosidade - PHP e Limite de consulta de dados

Tags: php, sql, query

Hoje enquanto fazia uma consulta por PhpMyAdmin do tipo
`SELECT * FROM tabela`
, reparei que, depois de se fazer uma consulta na base de dados automaticamente a query fica com o `LIMIT`, desta maneira `SELECT * FROM tabela LIMIT 0 , 30`, ou seja se estou correto, começa pelo primeiro registo e mostra 30 resultados. Isso me intrigou, porque no `PHP` eu faço essas querys e mando tudo para uma tabela, mas e se durante um ano eu fazer mais de 100 inscrições e quiser ve-las todas? eu nunca poderei prever o limite do mesmo. Em php pensei usar uma variável para o limite, que recebia o `COUNT` de todos os registos da tabela, ou então fazer uma subquery do tipo `SELECT * FROM TABELA LIMIT (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABELA)`. Apenas procuro métodos que possam ajudar futuramente.

Comment: Acho que é isso [Paginação script PHP](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/94890/91)

Comment: Na verdade eu ainda não entendi qual é a sua dúvida. Parece que você está simplesmente fazendo afirmações. Sim, o PhpMyAdmin limita os dados, mas se você determinar o "limit" na consulta, isso é alterado. Sim,  se você inserir 100 dados você verá apenas 30 (se apenas clicar na tabela) do PhpMyAdmin, mas nada que impeça de usar o `LIMIT` específico na sua query.

Comment: Também não entendi a duvida. Pelo que eu entendi você está usando uma consulta padrão do PhpMyAdmin web.

Comment: A minha dúvida é, basicamente, se fosse você num site que você fizesse, o que você faria para expor numa tabela mais de 100 dados. Sabendo que, você não iria saber quantas linhas de informação a base de dados tinha, apenas sabia que queria vê-las todas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> A minha dúvida é, basicamente, se fosse você num site que você
>   fizesse, o que você faria para expor numa tabela mais de 100 dados.
>   Sabendo que, você não iria saber quantas linhas de informação a base
>   de dados tinha, apenas sabia que queria vê-las todas

Acredito que agora eu entendi a sua pergunta.

Não, o LIMIT não é obrigatório em uma query. Você só deve usa-lo quando realmente quer restringir o número de registros que a query deve retornar, para um determinado número, em vez de mostrar todos.
Se você tem uma tabela com um número indeterminado de registros, e quer mostrar tadas as linhas, basta não colocar a cláusula LIMIT na query. Ex:

```
SELECT * FROM tabela
```

Vai buscar todos os dados da tabela.

O que o PhpMyAdmin faz, é adicionar um LIMIT de 30 na query, para evitar a listagem exagerada de dados, e assim não comprometer o desempenho da ferramenta...

Recomendo dar uma olhada: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select_limit.asp

Comment: esclarecido, obrigado :) Eu pensava que se nao metesse LIMIT, ele metia sozinho mesmo assim