# SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation

Tags: php, mysql

SQL:

```
"SELECT * FROM produto WHERE ($cliente=null OR cliente LIKE '%".$cliente."%')
AND ($n_cad=NULL
     OR n_cad=$n_cad)
AND ($cod=NULL
     OR id=$cod)
AND ($dt_inicial=NULL
     OR data_emissao >= $dt_inicial)
AND ($dt_final=NULL
     OR data_emissao <= $dt_final)
ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT ".$min.",".$max;
```

O erro:

> ```
> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an
> error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
> MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '=null OR
> n_cad=) AND (=null OR id=) AND (=null OR data_emissao >= ) AND
> (2017-02' at line 1
> ```

Comment: o mysql não aceita =null mas ele aceita campoX IS NULL, mas não se enquadra no teu contexto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como já respondi em sua [outra pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/186624/como-otimizar-sql-para-filtrar-resultados) o seu problema está na igualdade dos parâmetros.

Experimente trocar o simbolo de igualdade pelo comando `IS NULL`.

Sua consulta ficaria desta forma:

```
$consulta = "SELECT * FROM produto WHERE ($cliente IS null OR cliente LIKE '%".$cliente."%')
AND ($n_cad IS NULL
     OR n_cad=$n_cad)
AND ($cod IS NULL
     OR id=$cod)
AND ($dt_inicial IS NULL
     OR data_emissao >= $dt_inicial)
AND ($dt_final IS NULL
     OR data_emissao <= $dt_final)
ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT ".$min.",".$max;
```