# retornar linhas de uma query de bloco de 10 em 10 fazendo um laço nessa query?

Tags: php, mysql

Pessoa, estou com um problema. Por exemplo: preciso fazer um `SELECT` numa tabela enorme, e quero  que retorne linhas no intervalo de 10 em 10.

Por exemplo: `1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10` para `11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20`,
e por aí vai.

**Caso prático:**

Tenho uma tabela de 500 mil linhas. Preciso dessa 500 mil linhas, só que de 1000 em 1000:

```
select * from tabela limit 1000 offset 0;
```

O intervalo seria a para parar no 1000, e depois, fazer um outro select começando em 1001 e indo a 2000.

Só que preciso fazer isso um vez só num script PHP.

é mais o menos como fazer uma paginação mais seria que ser automático, o select teria que executar esse bloco de 1000 em 1000 até não ter mais linhas na tabela

Comment: intervalo seria o quê? dar uma pausa de X segundos? Exibir cada bloco de 10 em 10  sem dar pausas?

Comment: Talvez esteja falando de paginação. http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/26303/como-fazer-pagina%C3%A7%C3%A3o-php-e-mysql

Comment: Sua pergunta está faltando informações úteis. Poste o código do que você já tentou fazer, se tiver.

Comment: `LIMIT/OFFSET` se o seu banco permitir ou equivalente.

Comment: Vinicius, foi você que fez a edição em outra conta?

Comment: Eu cheguei nessa pergunta porque ela me foi sugerida na fila de análise (em um teste que eu fui reprovado, uma vez que eu votei para mantê-la aberta). O teste diz pra eu parar, olhar e escutar porque a pergunta tem problemas. Fazendo o que foi pedido, a pergunta na versão atual não parece ter problemas de entendimento (e eu entendo bem pouco de SQL). O que o AP precisa é consultar as linhas aos poucos, em um intervalo quantitativo informado. O @WallaceMaxters entendeu e até sugeriu uma resposta sobre paginação. Se a pergunta realmente deve permanecer fechada, não seria como duplicada?

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php 

var $quantidadeRegistro = 5000; //quantiade registro no banco

var $limit = 1000; 
var $offset = 0;

var $select = "";

//criar os select no banco
for($i = 1; $i <= $quantidadeRegistro ; $i += 1000){ 
    $select = $select + "select * from [tabela] limit " . $limit . " offset " . offset;
}

$offset = $limit;

if($quantidadeRegistro > $limit){
    $limit = $limit + 1000;
} else {
    $limit = $limit + ($quantidadeRegistro - $limit);
}
```

Acho que é mais ou menos isso que você, precisa!