# selecionar linhas de bloco em bloco de um intervalo de 10 em 10 fazendo um loop na query?

Tags: php, mysql

Tenho uma tabela de 500 mil linhas preciso dessa 500 mil linhas só que de 1000 em 1000 por exemplo select * from tabela limit 1000 offset 0; o intervalo seria a para parar no 1000 e depois faz um outro select começando 1001 a 2000 por exemplo só que preciso fazer isso um vez só num script php

Comment: Você terá que criar um sistema de paginação, e nele você irá informar quantos deve ser apresentado por pagina.

Comment: vou tentar valeu daniel

Comment: É a [mesma pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/116198/91)? você pode editar ela e adicionar mais detalhes, não precisa criar uma nova.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php 

var $quantidadeRegistro = 5000; //quantiade registro no banco

var $limit = 1000; 
var $offset = 0;

var $select = "";

//criar os select no banco
for($i = 1; $i <= $quantidadeRegistro ; $i += 1000){ 
    $select = $select + "select * from [tabela] limit " . $limit . " offset " . offset;
}

$offset = $limit;

if($quantidadeRegistro > $limit){
    $limit = $limit + 1000;
} else {
    $limit = $limit + ($quantidadeRegistro - $limit);
}

if($quantidadeRegistro > $limit){
$limit = $limit + 1000;
} else {

}

}
```

Acho que é mais ou menos isso que você, precisa!

Comment: olá, @Edvaldo. Seria legal você repostar sua resposta nessa aqui: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/116198/91