# Consulta de muitos dados MySQL e PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Pessoal o código abaixo faz o parser dos dados que estão no log da openvpn e armazena no banco de dados que por outros códigos são mostrados em uma página com tabela. Porém, são muitos registros em um arquivo de log! São mais de 6 mil (e vai ir subindo com o tempo) e isso está demorando um pouco e acabou quebrando o banco com "Too Many Conections" e também para mostrar os dados em uma tabela eu utilizo o seguinte:

```
$sql = "SELECT idvpn, comName, realAddr, byS, byR, virtAddr, since,    blockstatus, connectedOr FROM vpn";
$query = mysqli_query($conexao, $sql);
return $query;
```

Só que com esse código acima, ele demora quase 2 minutos pra exibir os dados em uma tabela (onde tem aquilo de próxima página com um plugin chamado DataTable). Por conta de inúmeras requisições - eu acho - eu não conseguia nem logar mais no site e os dados começaram a ser inseridos todos quebrados no banco... Preciso de ajuda urgente, preciso saber o que estou fazendo de errado!

Aqui vai o código do parser que quebra cada linha do log e pega as informações, verifica se já existe no banco, se não existir ele adiciona, se existir ele verifica se está no log e no banco, se sim ele atualiza pra conectado, se não ele atualiza pra desconectado.

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("*******", "root", "*******", "*******");
set_time_limit(0);
$pathlog = "log2.txt";

ovpnParser($con, $pathlog);

function checkDiff($con, &$isinlog){
// echo '<script>console.log("**** START CHECKDIFF ****")</script>';
$databArray = array(); // database array
$sql = "SELECT comName FROM vpn";
$query = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
while ($result = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
array_push($databArray, $result['comName']);
}
foreach($databArray as $newArray){
if(!in_array($newArray, $isinlog)){
  // echo '<script>console.log("database ok, log off...")</script>';
  $sql = "UPDATE vpn SET connectedOr = 'false' WHERE  comName =   '{$newArray}'"; // tem no bd mas não tem no log. ou seja, desconectado.

  $query = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
}
}
// echo '<script>console.log("**** END CHECKDIFF****")</script>'; 
}

function ovpnParser($con, $pathlog){
// echo '<script>console.log("**** START OVPN PARSER****")</script>';
$isinlog = array(); // log array

$inclients = false;
$handle = fopen($pathlog, "r");
$inclients = false;

while(!feof($handle)){
$line = fgets($handle, 4096);
if (substr($line, 0, 11) == "CLIENT_LIST"){
  if (preg_match("/CLIENT_LIST\t{1,}UNDEF(.*)UNDEF/", $line)){
    $inclients = false;
   }
   else{
    $inclients = true;
   }
  }
  if ($inclients){
  preg_match("/CLIENT_LIST(.*)UNDEF/", $line, $conteudo);
  $partes = preg_split("/\t{1,}/", trim($conteudo[1]));
  array_push($isinlog, $partes[0]);

  $sql = "SELECT comName FROM vpn WHERE  comName = '{$partes[0]}'";
  $query = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
  $rows = mysqli_num_rows($query);

  if ($rows == 0){
    // echo '<script>console.log("new register")</script>';
    $sql = "INSERT INTO vpn (comName, realAddr, virtAddr, byR, byS, since, blockstatus, connectedOr)
    VALUES ('{$partes[0]}', '{$partes[1]}', '{$partes[2]}', '{$partes[3]}', '{$partes[4]}', '{$partes[5]}', 'true', 'true')";
    $query = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
    }
  elseif ($rows > 0) {
    // echo '<script>console.log("log and database ok...")</script>';
    $sql = "UPDATE vpn SET byR = '{$partes[3]}', byS = '{$partes[4]}', connectedOr = 'true' WHERE  comName = '{$partes[0]}'";
    $query = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
  }
 }
 $inclients = false;
 }
// echo '<script>console.log("**** END OVPN PARSER ****")</script>';
checkDiff($con, $isinlog);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema é exatamente esse que você citou. Múltiplas conexões.

Isso acontece porque você faz essas conexões dentro dos `loops`. Abaixo eu exemplifiquei, com o seu próprio código, como arrumar isso, pois você está realizando consultas e inserções dentro de loops 4 vezes. Não será rápido arrumar tudo. Mas entendendo a lógica, já facilita muito.

Peguei a função `checkDiff()` para exemplificar. Não quis alterar seus comentários então os comentários em **MAIÚSCULOS** são os meus.

A lógica é simples:

- Vou criar uma string única, concatenando os valores dentro do loop, para realizar a inserção depois.
- Fora do loop farei a conexão e a inserção dos dados.

Veja:

```
function checkDiff($con, &$isinlog){
    // echo '<script>console.log("**** START CHECKDIFF ****")</script>';
    $databArray = array(); // database array
    $sql = "SELECT comName FROM vpn";

    $query = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

    while ($result = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){

        array_push($databArray, $result['comName']);

    }

    // COLOQUEI A PRIMEIRA PARTE DA STRING FORA DO FOREACH

    $sql = "UPDATE vpn SET connectedOr = 'false' WHERE ";

    // AGORA VAMOS CONCATENAR  A STRING PARA FAZER A INSERÇÃO DE UMA VEZ SÓ

    foreach($databArray as $newArray){

        if(!in_array($newArray, $isinlog)){
          // echo '<script>console.log("database ok, log off...")</script>';
          // AQUI É REALIZADA A CONCATENAÇÃO
          $sql .= " comName =   '{$newArray}' OR"; // tem no bd mas não tem no log. ou seja, desconectado.

        }

    }

    // VAMOS RETIRAR O ULTIMO ''OR'' PARA NÃO HAVER BUGS
    $sql = substr($sql, 0, -2);


    // REPARE QUE EU TIREI A QUERY DO FOREACH (AGORA A CONEXÃO SERÁ EXECUTA UMA VEZ)

    $query = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
    // echo '<script>console.log("**** END CHECKDIFF****")</script>'; 
}
```

Em todas as outras conexões você terá que fazer a mesma coisa. Só que as strings serão diferentes.

No primeiro caso usamos o `OR` para fazer um único `UPDATE`. Mas no caso do `INSERT` vamos usar uma **vírgula** para delimitar os valores.

**Exemplo:**

*Multipla inserção:*

```
INSERT INTO `usuarios` (`id`, `nome`) VALUES (0,'Cesar'),(0, 'Andrei')
```

Veja, a partir de agora, você sempre deverá criar seus scripts desta forma. Além de evitar esses problemas seu código ficará muito mais rápido.

Espero que isso te ajude.

Answer (score 2):

Bom não sei se entendi bem seu problema! Mas vi dois pontos:

1) A demora para exibir os registros na tela! Bom eu já tive problemas com a renderização de muitos registros, porque trava mesmo! Até renderizar 6mil registros na dom e via JS, realmente demora muito! A alternativa é deixar a paginação no php. Eu particularmente, não faço nenhuma aplicação sem  o doctrine, o sistema de paginação dele é ótimo!

[Paginação com PHP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/26303/como-fazer-pagina%C3%A7%C3%A3o-php-e-mysql) -
[Paginação com Doctrine](https://gist.github.com/novasky/5730900)

2) O problema de muitas conexões, pelo que entendi do seu código sempre que alguma ação, você já executa no banco. Inclusive dentro de um foreach!

```
foreach($databArray as $newArray){
 if(!in_array($newArray, $isinlog)){
  // echo '<script>console.log("database ok, log off...")</script>';
  $sql = "UPDATE vpn SET connectedOr = 'false' WHERE  comName =    '{$newArray}'"; // tem no bd mas não tem no log. ou seja, desconectado.
$query = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
}
}
```

Uma alternativa seria concatenar as querys e depois executa-las em uma só requisição:

```
$sql = '';
foreach($databArray as $newArray){
 if(!in_array($newArray, $isinlog)){
  // echo '<script>console.log("database ok, log off...")</script>';
  $sql .= "UPDATE vpn SET connectedOr = 'false' WHERE  comName =    '{$newArray}'; "; // tem no bd mas não tem no log. ou seja, desconectado.
}
}
```

e para executar essa $sql, você pode fazer assim: [mysqli multiple](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.multiple-statement.php)