# Expandir listagem ao clicar

Tags: jquery, html

Tenho um select que me retorna 40 registros. Quero imprimir inicialmente 10 deles e depois criar um botão *Ver mais* onde irá expandir a lista exibindo mais 10 itens até completar o meu total de 40 registros e sumir assim que acabar todos eles.

Um exemplo desse botão funcionando pode ser visto aqui no [Mercado Livre](http://produto.mercadolivre.com.br/MLB-704017623-misturador-de-agua-externo-torneira-aquecedor-solar-ou-gas-_JM#D[S:HOME,L:RECOMITEM-CORE-UNO-HOT,V:2]) no final das perguntas feitas ao vendedor.

Comment: Acho que o que você procura se chama "Paginação", você pode encontrar sobre isso em http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/26303/como-fazer-pagina%C3%A7%C3%A3o-php-e-mysql.

Comment: não é bem isso não, tudo será exibido na mesma página... eu só não quero que carregue tudo de uma vez para o caso do usuário não querer ler. mas se lhe interessar ele poderá clicar no botão e irá exibindo mais coisas a cada vez que clica... vc pode ver um exemplo identico do que eu quero no link do mercado livre quer postei, na parte onde exibe as perguntas ao vendedor

Comment: O mercado livre carrega TODAS as perguntas de uma só vez, ao menos nesse link!  Todas as perguntas "ocultas" estão com a classe `ch-hide`. Quando você clica em "Ver mais perguntas" ele simplesmente remove o `ch-hide`, até por  esse motivo é exibido de maneira imediata. Então, se deseja algo igual, carregue todos e então oculte X. Quando clicar torne os elementos visíveis. A outra forma é carregar por AJAX, ou seja, quando clicar envia um requisição para o servidor (que responde) e então exibe, sistema idêntico ao de paginação.

Comment: sim é isso mesmo que eu quero, carregar todos e ir mostrando de pouco em pouco ao clicar no botão até acabar a lista. Fico perdido em como criaria esse array e limitaria para sempre ir mostrando de dez em dez... sabe de algum exemplo? o comentário acima ja me abriu bastante o caminho de como fazer, obg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

você pode colocar todos os elementos com uma classe em comum, adicione uma classe com `display: none` à todos os elementos, e a cada click do `button` carregar você remove esta classe de 10 elementos.

```js
var quantidade = 10;
var carregar = document.getElementById("carregar");
var conteudos = document.querySelectorAll(".conteudo");
conteudos = [].slice.call(conteudos);
conteudos.forEach(function (conteudo, indice) {
  conteudo.classList.add("hide");
});

var onCarregarClick = function (event) {
  for (var indice = 0; indice < quantidade; indice++) {
    var conteudo = conteudos.shift();
    if (conteudo)
      conteudo.classList.remove("hide");
    if (conteudos.length == 0) {
      carregar.classList.add("hide");
      return;
    }
  }
}
carregar.addEventListener("click", onCarregarClick);
carregar.dispatchEvent(new Event("click"));
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="conteudo">Conteudo 01</div>
<div class="conteudo">Conteudo 02</div>
<div class="conteudo">Conteudo 03</div>
<div class="conteudo">Conteudo 04</div>
<div class="conteudo">Conteudo 05</div>
<div class="conteudo">Conteudo 06</div>
<div class="conteudo">Conteudo 07</div>
<div class="conteudo">Conteudo 08</div>
<div class="conteudo">Conteudo 09</div>
<div class="conteudo">Conteudo 10</div>
<div class="conteudo">Conteudo 11</div>
<div class="conteudo">Conteudo 12</div>
<div class="conteudo">Conteudo 13</div>
<div class="conteudo">Conteudo 14</div>
<div class="conteudo">Conteudo 15</div>
<div class="conteudo">Conteudo 16</div>
<div class="conteudo">Conteudo 17</div>
<div class="conteudo">Conteudo 18</div>
<div class="conteudo">Conteudo 19</div>
<div class="conteudo">Conteudo 20</div>
<div class="conteudo">Conteudo 21</div>
<div class="conteudo">Conteudo 22</div>
<div class="conteudo">Conteudo 23</div>
<div class="conteudo">Conteudo 24</div>
<div class="conteudo">Conteudo 25</div>
<div class="conteudo">Conteudo 26</div>
<div class="conteudo">Conteudo 27</div>
<div class="conteudo">Conteudo 28</div>
<div class="conteudo">Conteudo 29</div>
<div class="conteudo">Conteudo 30</div>
<div class="conteudo">Conteudo 31</div>
<div class="conteudo">Conteudo 32</div>
<div class="conteudo">Conteudo 33</div>
<div class="conteudo">Conteudo 34</div>
<div class="conteudo">Conteudo 35</div>
<div class="conteudo">Conteudo 36</div>
<div class="conteudo">Conteudo 37</div>
<input id="carregar" type="button" value="Carregar" />
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, funcionou perfeitamente!