# Marcar número da página acessada no momento (paginação PHP)

Tags: php

Fiz uma paginação para minha página, porém, não sei como posso fazer para que o número da pagina atual fique em destaque e escurecido. 
Poderiam me ajudar?

Segue o meu código:

```
<?php
//PAGINAÇAO
if ($registros_ > 3) {
//Verificar a pagina anterior e posterior


    $max_links = 6;

    $links_laterais = ceil($max_links / 2);

    $pagina_anterior = $pagina - $links_laterais;
    $pagina_posterior = $pagina + $links_laterais;

    print "<div class='container'>
<div>
                <ul class='pagination'>
                    <li>";
    if ($pagina_anterior > 0) {
        print "<a href='pesquisas.php?pagina=$pagina_anterior&tipo=$tipo&seletor=$seletor&filtro=$filtro' aria-label='Previous'>
                                <span aria-hidden='true'>&laquo;</span>
                            </a>";
    } else {
        print "<span aria-hidden='true'>&laquo;</span>";
    }
    print "</li>";
//Apresentar a paginacao

    for ($i = $pagina_anterior; $i < $pagina_posterior; $i++) {
        if (($i >=1) && ($i <= $num_pagina)){ 
        print"<li><a href='pesquisas.php?pagina=$i&tipo=$tipo&seletor=$seletor&filtro=$filtro'>$i</a></li>";
    }
    }

    print "<li>";
    if ($pagina_posterior <= $num_pagina) {
        print " <a href='pesquisas.php?pagina=$pagina_posterior&tipo=$tipo&seletor=$seletor&filtro=$filtro' aria-label='Previous'>
            <span aria-hidden='true''>&raquo;</span>
        </a>";
    } else {
        print "<span aria-hidden='true'>&raquo;</span>";
        }
    print "</div></div>";
}
//FIM PAGINAÇAO
?>
```

Consegui resolver da seguinte forma:

```html
<?php
//PAGINAÇAO
if ($registros_ > 3) {
//Verificar a pagina anterior e posterior


    $max_links = 6;

    $links_laterais = ceil($max_links / 2);

    $pagina_anterior = $pagina - $links_laterais;
    $pagina_posterior = $pagina + $links_laterais;

    print "<div class='container'>
<div>
                <ul class='pagination'>
                    <li>";
    if ($pagina_anterior > 0) {
        print "<a href='pesquisas.php?pagina=$pagina_anterior&tipo=$tipo&seletor=$seletor&filtro=$filtro' aria-label='Previous'>
                                <span aria-hidden='true'>&laquo;</span>
                            </a>";
    } else {
        print "<span aria-hidden='true'>&laquo;</span>";
    }
    print "</li>";
//Apresentar a paginacao

//Criei essa variavel com o código CSS
$numativo = "style='background-color: #4682B4; color: white;'";
//Criei essa variavel com o código CSS

    for ($i = $pagina_anterior; $i < $pagina_posterior; $i++) {
        if (($i >=1) && ($i <= $num_pagina)){ 
        //INCLUINDO ESSE TRECHO
        $ativo = ($i == $pagina) ? $numativo : '';
        //INCLUINDO ESSE TRECHO
        print"<li><a href='pesquisas.php?pagina=$i&tipo=$tipo&seletor=$seletor&filtro=$filtro'
<!--Adicionei a variavel aqui para saber qual a numeração está ativa no momento-->
        $ativo
<!--Adicionei a variavel aqui para saber qual a numeração está ativa no momento-->
        >$i</a></li>";
    }
    }

    print "<li>";
    if ($pagina_posterior <= $num_pagina) {
        print " <a href='pesquisas.php?pagina=$pagina_posterior&tipo=$tipo&seletor=$seletor&filtro=$filtro' aria-label='Previous'>
            <span aria-hidden='true''>&raquo;</span>
        </a>";
    } else {
        print "<span aria-hidden='true'>&raquo;</span>";
        }
    print "</div></div>";
}
//FIM PAGINAÇAO
?>
```

Comment: Na resposta em https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/26303/3635 tem exemplo de como mostrar qual é a página atual e a partir dai você customiza como desejar.

Answer (score 3):

Basta comparar com a página corrente:

```
if (($i >=1) && ($i <= $num_pagina)){
   if ($i == $pagina) {
      // se é a atual, nem do link precisa (conforme o caso)
      print"<li><strong>$i</strong></li>";
   } else {
      // se é diferente da atual, usa link e estiliza diferentemente
      print"<li><a href='pesquisas.php?pagina=$i&tipo=$tipo&seletor=$seletor&filtro=$filtro'>$i</a></li>";
   }
}
```

Claro que dá pra simplificar, o importante é a comparação de `$i` com `$pagina`:

```
if (($i >=1) && ($i <= $num_pagina)){
   print "<li".($i==$pagina?' class="destacado"':'')."><a href='pesquisas.php?pagina=$i&tipo=$tipo&seletor=$seletor&filtro=$filtro'>$i</a></li>";
}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pela resposta amigo, mas, dessa forma não funcionou.

Comment: Opa, Veriquei agora e vi que foi descuido, não percebi, mas , funcionou sim, porém, o número não fica em destaque, ele se desloca e fica fora do arranjo dos números no linlk.

Comment: Bom, ai você tem que formatar o CSS, etc. Note que foi só um exemplo, se precisar pode usar com link mesmo pra manter o style

Comment: Na segunda opção, ele usa um "class = destacado" mas vc tem que por no CSS essa classe, conforme o resto da página

Comment: Nada impede de repetir o código de cima com link e tudo e por só o "strong" a mais também. O importante é você entender que pode por o código que quiser em cada parte do IF.

Comment: Um exemplo seria usar o 2o código (o simplificado) e no CSS acrescentar `.destacado {background-color:#900;text-weight:bold}` - essa classe seria aplicada só na numeração da página corrente