# Encapsulamento de quantias aleatórias - é possível?

Tags: php, html, jquery, mysql

Estou tentando fazer com que o php mande uma resposta para o arquivo javaScript com  informações, no qual o javaScript faz um pedido para o php em ajax, e o php mande quantia de informações em quantia aleatória, o php irá puxar do banco todos os registros e responderá o ajax com essas informações, e por fim o javaScript vai montar o html, eu no começo pensei em montar o html no php, mas eu vi que isso não é uma boa opção.

OBS: existira dois arquivos PHP um que vai gerar o banco e outro que vai receber o html pela resposta do ajax.

Os meus códigos estão logo abaixo.

javascrip

```
$.ajax({
url : "file.php",
type : "POST",
data : { alpha : null},
success : function(){console.log("work")},
error : function(){console.log("error")}
});
```

PHP

```
$q = "SELECT * FROM `table`";
$r = $conn->query($q);

while ($row = $r->fetch_assoc()) {

}

echo json_encode($var); //Var || array || objeto
```

A minha pergunta, como eu faço para enviar essas informações de volta para o javaScript?

Comment: Tudo o que você *exibir* com o PHP, sendo por `echo`, `print`, ou qualquer outro meio, será definido como corpo da resposta HTTP retornada ao cliente (neste caso, o JS).

Comment: Esqueci de escrever que são dois arquivos distintos, foi mal =/

Comment: Como assim dois arquivos distintos?

Comment: São três arquivos, dois PHP e um JS, um é o Index.php que vai receber o código post $(“#id”).html(“RESP”) e o outro PHP que vai gerar o banco.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para retornar os dados do PHP você pode usar a função `echo`. Ela irá retornar o que for passado como parâmetro.

```
$q = "SELECT * FROM `table`";
$r = $conn->query($q);
$resposta ='';
while ($row = $r->fetch_assoc()) {
    // Aqui você ajusta a resposta como quiser.
    $resposta .= $row;
}
echo $resposta;
```

O JavaScript então vai receber o que estiver na variável `$resposta` quando for dado o `echo`.

Comment: O problema não está sendo enviar por echo, mas sim como gerar quantias aleatórias para enviar por echo json_encode($var) //Var || array || objeto

Comment: Desculpa, não entendi a pergunta, que quantias aleatórias você quer gerar? Você diz gerar um número aleatório no banco de dados?

Comment: Isso, por exemplo, se o banco tem 125 itens ele vai puxar 125 itens, o que define a quantia de informação é a quantidade do banco.

Comment: Mas aquele laço while só vai encerrar quando o número de respostas do banco acabar. Se você tiver 1 linha de resposta ele roda 1 vez, se tiver 125 ele roda 125 vezes.

Comment: Mas eu preciso puxar o banco inteiro para retornar as informações por json_encode()

Comment: O problema então é determinar quantas linhas vão ser passadas por vez? Como fazer a paginação dos dados?

Comment: Sim eu pensei em fazer isso, pensei bem depois de eu ter feito o post, mas eu quis acreditar que tinha uma maneira de fazer com apenas uma paginação só.

Comment: De repente essa questão te ajuda nesse caso https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/26303/como-fazer-pagina%c3%a7%c3%a3o-php-e-mysql#26400