# Fazer paginação no SQL

Tags: sql, asp, paginação

Tenho um SELECT que precisa virar um PROC com paginação para ser consumido por uma página ASP (clássico).
Poderiam me ajudar?

Segue abaixo o SELECT:

```
SELECT
A.NOMUSU,
A.NOMMAE,
C.ATIVID,
B.DSCEND,
B.NUMEND,
B.DSCBAI,
B.DSCCID,
B.CODUFE,
B.CODCEP,
D.NUMDDD,
D.NUMTEL
FROM TBCADUSU A
INNER JOIN TBCADEND B ON (A.CODUSU = B.CODUSU)
INNER JOIN TBCADCRE C ON (A.CODUSU = C.CODUSU)
INNER JOIN TBCADCTO D ON (A.CODUSU = D.CODUSU)
WHERE B.TIPEND = 2
```

Comment: Não sei qual banco você está usando, mas veja o link que o @Barbetta passou, se for `mysql` pode usar `limit`, veja essa pergunta: [paginação mysql](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/26303/57220)

Comment: Pefeito! Me ajudou demais.. estou usando SQL mesmo.. Obrigado