# Mostrar apenas 1 registro por vez com botão para ir para o seguinte

Tags: mysqli, sql-select, html-select

**Boa noite a todos.**

Gostaria de: Mostrar registros sequencialmente, (1 por vez), em uma página web para um conjunto de mais de 100 mil registros. Consigo mostrar todos de uma vez, mas gostaria de apenas 1 por vez com botão ir para o próximo. Minha tabela é unica e tem 22 campos.

```
<?php
$conexao = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'aiseco14_america', 'Aise15481415*', 'aiseco14_cedato');

$sql = $conexao->query("Select cnpj, empresas, obs, data From empresas");
if($sql){ // If $sql is True
    while($exibe = $sql->fetch_assoc()){
        foreach($exibe as $key => $value){
            echo "<br />" . $value;
        }}}
?>
```

Coloquei 3 campos apenas para ilustrar. 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Desde já agradeço as orientações

Comment: precisa paginar então, aqui uma pergunta relacionada: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/26303/como-fazer-pagina%c3%a7%c3%a3o-php-e-mysql

Comment: Agradeço muito sua sugestão. Fiz o teste com todos e não seria isso. O propósito de mostrar um por um é impedir que o usuário escolha com qual cliente trabalhar e deixe os menos lucrativos de lado e por isso a paginação não é interessante. E a ultima sugestão mostra todos produtos lado a lado na horizontal. Mesmo assim, muito obrigado pela atenção.