# Paginação de Texto em PHP e Mysql

Tags: php, mysqli, paginação, texto

Tenho um texto grande com muitos caracteres e preciso fazer ele ficar em umas 5 páginas com opção de PROXIMA PÁGINA e PÁGINA ANTERIOR.

Pesquisei e não encontro nenhum tutorial sobre o assunto, alguém pode me ajudar?

Preciso de uma maneira diferente de javascript que encontrei aqui.
O código abaixo está reduzido para testes.

```html
<?
include("config/config.php");

////////////////NOVO MYSQLI////////////////
$seleciona = "SELECT * FROM news_ind where id = '$idnoticias2'";
$result = $conecta->query($seleciona);
$ver = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
////////////////NOVO MYSQLI////////////////

$noticia = $ver["noticia"];

?>


<? echo $noticia; ?>
```

Comment: Recomendo ler este post: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/26303/como-fazer-pagina%C3%A7%C3%A3o-php-e-mysql

Comment: Conseguiu verificar a resposta? Não esqueça de aceitá-la caso  esteja satisfeito com a mesma.

Answer (score 0):

A "páginação" pode ser feita tanto na sua base de dados quanto no código. Independentemente de onde for feita, a lógica é a mesma.

O 1o passo é determinar o tamanho de letras de cada página e isso pode ser fixo no seu código. O 2o passo é calcular a quantidade de páginas. O 3o é fazer a páginação e pegar o conteúdo da página atual.

Considerando que as páginas têm até 100 caracteres e um texto com 450 caracteres, poderia ser feito:

```php
$tam_pagina = 100;
$tam_texto = strlen($noticia); // ex: 450
$pagina_atual = 2; // iniciando em 0; neste caso vai até 4
$total_paginas = ceil($tam_texto / $tam_pagina);
$inicio_pagina = $pagina_atual * $tam_pagina;

$texto_pagina = substr($noticia, $inicio_pagina, $tam_pagina);
```

Ressalva:

- É preciso considerar que a notícia tem somente textos (não sejá HTML ou markdown, por exemplo, pois parte de um marckup pode ficar numa página e a outra parte em outra página.

Alternativas:

- Vc pode criar um marcador próprio para definir onde o conteúdo é dividido em páginas, permitindo ter markups no conteúdo (como o "leia mais" do Wordpress - `<!--more-->`);
- Vc pode criar um controle na sua tabela (ou em outra tabela) indicando os índices do `substring`, permitindo ter páginas com tamanhos diferentes, por exemplo.